# Transferring Data Out of CiviCRM

Tags: error, database, export

Some time ago we transferred data from CiviCRM to a different CRM (YourMembership). However, it has become apparent that we have not collected all of the data.

We have the web version CiviCRM 4.6.21. I am trying to export ALL of the data, but I keep getting warnings and errors that there is not enough memory in one of the lines of code.

In addition to that, even when I segment the data and export it in chunks, some of the data in each individual records appears to exist only within the record, and not in some master spreadsheet (e.g. ticket sales).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the search results export function or exporting data directly from the database?

Comment: You will have to be more clear about what you mean with "all of the data" before I can give you a sensible answer? I am sure there are parts in the database which you do not want to export.

Comment: I am trying to export the full database: all member records, all event records, all contacts/constituents, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Exporting 'all' data is not a simple process. You will need to eg

- Find all Contacts: export including all Custom Fields using for Contacts
- Find all Contribution: export including all Custom Fields using for Cont
- Find all Events: export including all Custom Fields using for Cont

Comment: Thanks! I tried this method. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error. Any thoughts on what to do? 500 SERVER ERROR
Previously the error implied there was a memory problem.

Comment: maybe a constraint due to your hosting. you may need to grab smaller chunks, or try to find someone who is happy to work from a copy of the db (assuming you can get one via your host) to do the data migration

Comment: will do thank you!